# OpenCV: find contours of the object with different backgrounds

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm trying to figure out how to find the contours of an object on Xrays.
I can’t attach the original images that I work with, because they are protected by copyright. 
Similar example:
https://ibb.co/LgzSs7m

I can't just use thresholding and find contours for two reasons:

1. There are shadows on some pictures (like this: https://ibb.co/FmvSRXc, https://ibb.co/S5vsQj1) and its color is very similar to the object color. So, binarization is confused because of this (I used blurring, it doesn't improve the results).
2. Sometimes there is a noise in the background (hair, etc), and it is also taken by binarization as part of the object.

I also tried to use `cv.adaptiveThreshold` and do something like this https://answers.opencv.org/question/182345/how-do-i-draw-only-external-contour/
but I didn’t succeed due to the same problems:

1. Not only objects but also shadows on the image create edges
2. The contour must be closed, but sometimes there is a noise in the background (or background color is very similar on object color), and in these places the contour becomes broken. I can't connect nearest contours because in this case foreign objects generated by noise also will be included in the contour.

So my question is: maybe there are some techniques to improve edge detection? Apply some filters, compare density or something else?

Comment: Try to apply morphologic transformations, median / laplace / gaussian filters, e.t.c.

Comment: You can make an opening operation cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel) to remove noise or look other morphological operations : docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html